# Any way to get all data types within a custom object?

Tags: java, android, caching

I'm developing an [open source API](https://github.com/widowmaker110/byteme) for measuring run-time allocation for custom objects easily. While I can write the cache handling algorithms just fine, I'm having an issue accessing all of the data types within a custom object organically. I'm wanting to write this API to take **any** custom object so long as it has the following data types currently supported:

- Int
- String
- Short
- Byte
- Long
- Float
- Double
- Char
- Boolean
- Bitmap (for Android only but can be excluded)

For instance, take this custom object class

```
package productions.widowmaker110.byteme;

/**
 * Created by Widowmaker110 on 11/20/2015.
 *
 * This object class is meant to mimick possible data types held within a single object
 *
 * For simplicity, I will be mimicking a simplified user profile data
 */
public class ExampleObject {

    private String Name;
    private int Age;
    private String Location;
    private String Sex;
    private String Description;

    /**
     * Empty Constructor
     */
    public ExampleObject() {}

    /**
     * Basic constructor with initializing data
     *
     * @param _Name String with the name of the user
     * @param _Age Integer with the age of the user
     * @param _Location String containing the curret city and state of the user
     * @param _Sex String Male, Female, Transgender, or Other
     * @param _Description String short blurb about the user
     */
    public ExampleObject(String _Name, int _Age, String _Location, String _Sex, String _Description)
    {
        this.setName(_Name);
        this.setAge(_Age);
        this.setLocation(_Location);
        this.setSex(_Sex);
        this.setDescription(_Description);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        Age = age;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        Location = location;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return Sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        Sex = sex;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is take something like this and "transfer" all of the data points to my cache handling class while maintaining the object in its current form if I can help it. My first idea was to have an object have an array of every data type of a given object but then that seems convoluted to me to deconstruct a custom object in such a way. I might be looking at it wrong but if I do something like:

```
Object(int[] int_array, String[] string_array, short[] short_array,
        long[] long_array, byte[] byte_array, float[] float_array,
        double[] double_array, char[] char_array, boolean[] boolean_array,
        Bitmap[] bitmap_array)
```

And ask the programmer to enter in all of their data points by placing them in an array.

My end goal for this API is to drop it into a project and have all of that nasty cache handling done for you instantly.

*EDIT* My apologies for making it unclear. I was trying to give the whole scope of the project but may have given too much. Is there any way to take a custom class and parse it without ever knowing what fields are available as long as they fall into the bullet-point list I made at the top? I can do the caching part myself. Does that make it clearer?

*EDIT #2* JFPicard pointed out using Java reflection for this sort of handling. After looking at the [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodModifiers.html) and these:

- [Jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html)
- [JavaCodeGeeks](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/reflection/java-reflection-example/)

I found something like this to be extremely helpful.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

...

Method[] methods = MyObject.class.getMethods();

for(Method method : methods){
    System.out.println("method = " + method.getName());
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. The only question that I see here is in the title, and that question is unclear. Could you perhaps explain, in greater detail, what your question is?

Comment: What kind of "cache handling" are you trying to automate?

Comment: Reflection seems the only logical solution, here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you need to use reflection to get all the getters of the object and get the data to do something.

Here's a good tutorial to help you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodModifiers.html

Comment: This is amazing. I didn't know they had this out there. Looking over the code, it seems to fit extremely well into what I'm wanting to do. Let me give it a spin and I will mark this as best answer if it works. +1

Comment: I checked the documentation and some examples online, this is exactly what I needed. I will post an edit of some code snippets for others.